# Youtube video embed error in IE8

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed any video in a page, but it does not work in IE8

```
<object width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1&enablejsapi=1"</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed id="ytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1&enablejsapi=1"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  allowscriptaccess="always"
  width="425" height="344">
</embed>
</object>
```

The video appears but I get javascript error and no access to the player!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have add the movie parameter for some browsers like

<param name="movie" value="VID_URL" />

Also move the

type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

to the object tag and add the data="VID_URL" property.